# Ubuntu Not Booting After Install. No Secure boot Options in Bios

Tags: uefi, bios

So i'm trying to install Ubuntu Server on some old hardware i bought. But after successfully installing and rebooting the pc cannot find any bootable devices. I searched the internet and all the answers rely on UEFI trust and secure boot shenanigans. But i checked and i do not have any of those options.

When installing I see this screen [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioko4.png)

for a very long time.